# paussing figure of presentation beamer

Tags: beamer, tikz-styles, tikz-trees, pause, uncover

[image]

I want to display the graph in beamer so that at each click of the entry we see the next step but of course in a single graph

```
\begin{figure}[!h]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1.5cm,>=latex]
\draw [->] (-4.5,-1)--(.5,-1);
\foreach \i in {-4,...,0} {
  \draw (\i,-.9)--(\i,-1.1) node[below] {\i};
}
\foreach \i/\j in {-4/4,-4/3,-4/2,-4/1,-3/2,-2/3,-3/1,-2/2,-1/3,-1/4,0/3,0/4} {\node[draw,circle,fill=cyan!9](\i_\j) at (\i,4-\j) {$\j$};
}
\foreach \i/\j in {-3/4,-2/1,-1/2,-3/3,-2/4,-1/1,0/2,0/1} {\node[draw,circle,dash pattern=on 1.5pt off 1.5pt](\i_\j) at (\i,4-\j) {$\j$};
}
\foreach \j in {2,1} \draw[->](-4_\j)--(-3_1);  \draw[->](-4_4)--(-3_2);
\draw[->](-3_1)--(-2_2);
\draw[->] (-3_2)--(-2_3);
\draw[->](-3_3)--(-2_4);
\draw[->](-2_4)--(-1_4);
\draw[->](-2_2)--(-1_3);
\draw[->](-4_3)--(-3_2);
 \draw[->](-1_4)--(0_3); \draw[->](-1_3)--(0_4);

\draw[->,dash pattern=on 1.5pt off 1.5pt] (-3_4)--(-2_3);
\draw[->,dash pattern=on 1.5pt off 1.5pt] (-2_1)--(-1_3);
\draw[->,] (-2_3)--(-1_4);
\draw[->,dash pattern=on 1.5pt off 1.5pt] (-1_1)--(0_2);
\draw[->,dash pattern=on 1.5pt off 1.5pt] (-1_2)--(0_1);
% les légendes au dessus du graphe
\draw (-3.5,3.7) node [scale=0.7] {$u_3=0.12$};
\draw (-2.5,3.7) node [scale=0.7] {$u_2=0.52$};
\draw (-1.5,3.7) node [scale=0.7] {$u_1=0.9$};
\draw (-0.5,3.7) node [scale=0.7] {$u_0=0.47$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\caption{troisième étape du couplage en arrière}
\end{figure}
```

so that each arrow of first state generates the peremiemier ensuit the second state and so following consequently in goes back in the time and one remakes the same states 
after the states that did not get arrows ol draw it by chest

Comment: I heard there is a bemer-overlay tikzlibrary, but cannot find it.  You could overlay tikzpictures using [remember picture, overlay] and add them one at a time.  You could also copy and paste the whole thing, using [opacity=0] for the parts to remain invisible.

Comment: (For those viewing this, fyi.)  OP reposted the same question 40 minutes later at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/440479/107497.

Comment: If you like an answer and it was helpful, please consider [upvoting](//tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) (by clicking on the arrows next to the score) and marking it as [accepted answer](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓).

Answer (score 3):

Using a much more minimal MWE. this illustrate my comment.  Note that you have to run LaTeX twice to get the first three slides to align.  The `opacity=0` approach works better for centering (figure environment) although you have to be careful not to add extra spaces.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
  \node[draw,circle] (A) {First};
  \path (4,0);% set right boundary for centering
\end{tikzpicture}
\onslide<2-> {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \node[draw,circle,right=1.5cm] (B) at (A) {Second};
  \draw[->] (A) -- (B);
  \end{tikzpicture}}
\onslide<3-> {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \node[draw,circle,right=1.5cm] (C) at (B) {Third};
  \draw[->] (B) -- (C);
  \end{tikzpicture}}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}
\only<1> {\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[draw,circle] (A) {First};
  \begin{scope}[opacity=0]
    \node[draw,circle,right=1.5cm] (B) at (A) {Second};
    \draw[->] (A) -- (B);
    \node[draw,circle,right=1.5cm] (C) at (B) {Third};
    \draw[->] (B) -- (C);
  \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}}%
\only<2>{\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[draw,circle] (A) {First};
  \node[draw,circle,right=1.5cm] (B) at (A) {Second};
  \draw[->] (A) -- (B);
  \begin{scope}[opacity=0]
    \node[draw,circle,right=1.5cm] (C) at (B) {Third};
    \draw[->] (B) -- (C);
  \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}}%
\only<3>{\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[draw,circle] (A) {First};
  \node[draw,circle,right=1.5cm] (B) at (A) {Second};
  \draw[->] (A) -- (B);
  \node[draw,circle,right=1.5cm] (C) at (B) {Third};
  \draw[->] (B) -- (C);
  \end{tikzpicture}}%
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```